# clone function is not working on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, clone

I've created a clone function on html file. But there's a weird error in code. when I put two ending 'div' in same line, the JavaScript code just work fine. but when I beautify html code or put the last ending tag in another line, the JavaScript just doesn't work. please look at the commented line

```
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-2 m-3 bg-primary" id="show">working</div>
    <button id="bt" class="btn btn-outline-primary ml-4 mt-2" onclick="hide()">remove</button>

<div id="error" class="text-danger ml-3"></div>
    <div id="myList" style="list-style-type:none;" class="mt-3">
        <div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username"
                    aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon2"
                        onclick="removeIt()">X</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div></div> <!-- this line is causing issue -->

    <button onclick="addElement()" class="btn btn-outline-primary ml-4 mt-2">Add</button>

    
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="numbers">
                Number Of Row
            </label>
            <input type="number" class="form-input" name="" id="numbers" value="1">
        </div>
        <button onclick="passNumber()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Go</button>
</div>
<script>
    let error = document.getElementById('error');

    function passNumber(){
        let numbers = document.getElementById('numbers').value;
        for(let i = 1; i <= numbers; i++){
            addElement();
        }
    }
    
    function hide() {
        document.getElementById('show').style.display = 'none';
    }
    function addElement() {
        error.innerHTML = '';
        let item = document.getElementById('myList').lastChild;
        let cln = item.cloneNode(true);
        document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(cln);
    }
    function removeIt() {
        let list = document.getElementById('myList');
        if(list.childNodes.length == 2){
             error.innerHTML=`you cant delete the last input box`;
        }else{
            let length = list.childNodes.length;
            list.removeChild(list.childNodes[length-1]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

this code works fine. but when I change the code into below lines, then the JavaScript just don't work at all -

```
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-2 m-3 bg-primary" id="show">working</div>
    <button id="bt" class="btn btn-outline-primary ml-4 mt-2" onclick="hide()">remove</button>

<div id="error" class="text-danger ml-3"></div>
    <div id="myList" style="list-style-type:none;" class="mt-3">
        <div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username"
                    aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon2"
                        onclick="removeIt()">X</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- this line is causing issue -->

    <button onclick="addElement()" class="btn btn-outline-primary ml-4 mt-2">Add</button>

    
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="numbers">
                Number Of Row
            </label>
            <input type="number" class="form-input" name="" id="numbers" value="1">
        </div>
        <button onclick="passNumber()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Go</button>
</div>
<script>
    let error = document.getElementById('error');

    function passNumber(){
        let numbers = document.getElementById('numbers').value;
        for(let i = 1; i <= numbers; i++){
            addElement();
        }
    }
    
    function hide() {
        document.getElementById('show').style.display = 'none';
    }
    function addElement() {
        error.innerHTML = '';
        let item = document.getElementById('myList').lastChild;
        let cln = item.cloneNode(true);
        document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(cln);
    }
    function removeIt() {
        let list = document.getElementById('myList');
        if(list.childNodes.length == 2){
             error.innerHTML=`you cant delete the last input box`;
        }else{
            let length = list.childNodes.length;
            list.removeChild(list.childNodes[length-1]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`lastChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild) is the last child node of *any kind*, including text nodes. By moving the closing `</div>` tag, you're adding a text node.

You could use [`lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/lastElementChild) instead to get only the last *element* in the list.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("container1").childNodes.length); // 2
console.log(document.getElementById("container2").childNodes.length); // 3
```

```html
<div id="container1">
    <div>x</div></div>
<div id="container2">
    <div>x</div>
</div>
```

---

Side note: Your HTML is invalid. `div` elements cannot be direct children of `ul` elements. `ul` elements are expected to contain `li` elements as their only direct (element) children.

Comment: Hello T.J. Crowder. I didn't remove the closing tag, I put it on the second line. the thing is when two ending tag is in a single line, the js works fine. but when I put the last ending tag/ending tag of the parent tag on another line. the javascript just doesn't work. You can use the code on a code editor and check out what I'm saying.

Comment: @MarufAli - Sorry, that was a typo in the answer (I originally wrote "mroving" by accident, later saw it and incorrectly changed it to "removing". It was meant to be "moving.") It's *moving* the end tag that adds the text node at the end. Did you try `lastElementChild`?